# Is it possible to automatically copy every item that enters clipboard in React Native (a ios/andriod Clipboard Manager app idea)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, clipboard, clipboardmanager

I am looking to make a clipboard manager within React Native. The concept is that everything you copy into the clipboard will be saved into the clipboard manager so that you can access items you copied in the past. For example, you might want to access a piece of text you copied 2 days ago.

I was hoping to build the app in React Native for both Android and iOS. Is it possible to implement this with React Native? I have tried searching everything I can but nothing seems to have come up and I do not want to begin implementation without knowing if it will be possible.

Bonus: it would be a huge bonus if someone has example code of how you might go about implementing this, but I know this is asking lots!

Comment: Do you want to access the clipboard content from things that you have copied outside the react native application?

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for replying! Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. thanks

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. This would require that the react native application has access to the clipboard from the operating system and I am almost certain that this is prohibited by security.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply, that would make sense if it's the case. But annoying for the creation of a clipboard manager ;D